# Unity3D Point lights in large scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate, deferred-rendering

I'm currently building a large scene in Unity that has a lot of point lights. Each room in the scene (~40 rooms) has 2 point lights and I am using deferred rendering (to enabled shadows so that light doesn't leak out of the room).

When using forward rendering my game runs at 60 fps, but when switching to deferred lighting it runs around 25-30 fps (because its calculating the soft shadows for the point lights I'm assuming).

How can I solve this problem while still preventing lights from leaking through walls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method, while complex, is to dynamically load and unload rooms separately, so that only the lights, polygons, and other information is present when those rooms are visible to the player. If you have a way to segment the scene to better minimize the amount of data to process, then you can get away with this as a hack. That's my only recommendation that's simple enough to explain in a small amount of time, and obviously, it's pretty dependent on the type of game you're making.

Comment: You can use triggers to get an event when the player moves somewhere, and use that to determine when to load or unload the room.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I might be able to make this work. And it doesn't look like anyone has a better solution.